# How to retrieve API key safely from .env file into javascript View - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have the key placed safely in .env file and I would like to make an ajax request to a paid API service.
I have the Javascript file (containing ajax code) which is in public/ajax.js

I can retrieve in this way, put this line of code : `$key = env('SECRET_API_KEY');` in controller and pass it to javascript directly using https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer  but then I am forced to put `@include('footer')` in some X page. So, when I check the source I see my API key :/

I am able to pull the data successfully but **How to prevent this?**

my current url : `url:"http://johndoe?param1=abc&param2=def&_token="+key,` in Ajax code.

If I directly put this in javascript `$key = env('SECRET_API_KEY');` I get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: env is not defined`

**What is the best approach to retrieve api key?**

Comment: If you use the API key in JS it will be visible to the end user. If you don't want it to be visible you will have to set up an "API proxy". Your JS calls your Php code which in turn calls the API with the key

Comment: @jimL can you show an example or steps to achieve in my case.

Comment: Do not make the call from your JavaScript application. Make the call to your server, which will call the API. Then, your server can return the API response to your ajax request.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Can you please show, how to do in laravel ? Because i understand theoretically but dont know how to do it. JS is client side, so anything kept would be public. I need some server side script, that does the get request and prints output or response. Right?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy what if i dont want even the response to be directly accessed by going to http://example.com/abc.json page. I only want my application to make use of the response and want to restrict all other kind of access to the data i m retriving. Steps on how to approach would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a route that your JS will call, from that route, define a controller and function that will handle the request and make the API call to the paid service.

```
Route::get('api-call', 'APIController@call');

//APIController
//use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
//use GuzzleHttp\Client;
...

public function call(Request $request)
{
    $params = $request->all();

    $api_key = env('SECRET_API_KEY');
    $url = 'url-to-paid-service?' . $params . '&key=' . $api_key; 
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->get($url);

    return response()->json($res->getBody());
}
```

From your ajax, make the call `http://your-own-site/api-call`

Comment: thanks for the solution. I will try now. I have to do this every 1 second. What piece of code do I put to repeat every 1 second?

Comment: What is with $params? do I need to include in order for it to work? $url = "url-to-domain?param1=value1&param2=value2&_token="+$api_key;

Comment: In this case, `$params` = `param1=value1&param2=value2` because I already took those with `$request->all();`

Comment: You will have to call it from JS every second using `setInterval()` : https://www.sitepoint.com/setinterval-example/

Comment: I get the part Client side does the call to /api and and server side gets the data. But if there are 100 users who visit example.com simultaneously would Client-side talking to Server-side and Server-side talking to data api be 1 endpoint or 100 endpoints? Behind the scene how does Client-Server-data_api work?

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia "1 endpoint or 100 endpoints?" as end-point simply means where all the different ways reach or try to reach, there is 1 end-point, and each of 100 visitiors would make yet another separate request to said 1 end-point.